# Query Two Woocommerce Standard Tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

**Answer**: Managed to answer my own question below, open to feedback still.

**The problem**: There is something wrong with my `INNER JOIN` statement. My code works fine with just one table.

**My goal** is to query out a `zone_name` from `woocommerce_shipping_zones` based off of a zip code that is entered into a form by the user and then passed in to my query function as a `location_code` for the `woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations` table. I am having difficulty getting results despite the zip I am checking existing withing `woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations` table and a matching `zone_id` in `woocommerce_shipping_zones`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['checkZip']) && isset($_POST['submittedZip'])) {
            //is the cast to int needed?
            $submittedZip = (int)$_POST['submittedZip'];
            debug_to_console($submittedZip);
            prntPage($submittedZip);
        }

        //query for pulling in shipping data
        function prntPage($submittedZip) {
            global $wpdb;
            // The SQL query
            if($submittedZip) {
                $results =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.location_code, {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_name ".
                            "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
                            "WHERE location_code = '$submittedZip' ".
                            "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
                            "ON {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id ");
                // Loop though rows data
                foreach( $results as $row ){
                    print_r($row);
                    debug_to_console($row);
                }
            }
        }

        //function to print to console, used for debugging php
        function debug_to_console($data) {
            $output = $data;
            $typeOfTest = getType($data);
            if (is_array($output))
                $output = implode(',', $output);
        
            echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: " . $output . ", Type: " . $typeOfTest . "' );</script>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following caused it to work. Had to do the join prior to the `WHERE` statement.

```
      
        //query for pulling in shipping data
        function prntPage($submittedZip) {
            global $wpdb;
            // The SQL query
            if($submittedZip) {
                $results =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_name ".
                            "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
                            "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
                            "ON {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id ".
                            "WHERE location_code = '$submittedZip' ");
                            
                // Loop though rows data
                foreach( $results as $row ){
                    print_r($row);
                    //debug_to_console($row);
                }
            }
        }
```